# Can we decode this base64 value

Tags: encryption, cryptography, base64

hi i have a value which is base64 but i am unable to decode it

```
W/nsnEnU2cMBgd55IQHI1e6qj9hFirVEsk6TEKfrZjbF7iJI40VmkLvoxegJzbgD4BvpYAemFitz5z+c8XOCJCEewXXKL9e/AGb8eUPPlZHbi770+fbH0D0=
```

Can you please help me

Comment: What did you try to decode it? And what problems did you get? It's a straight forward thing, in most languages (you didn't specify any) you have libs for this and just need one call to decode it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'W/ ... D0=' | base64 -D | xxd

00000000: 5bf9 ec9c 49d4 d9c3 0181 de79 2101 c8d5  [...I......y!...
00000010: eeaa 8fd8 458a b544 b24e 9310 a7eb 6636  ....E..D.N....f6
00000020: c5ee 2248 e345 6690 bbe8 c5e8 09cd b803  .."H.Ef.........
00000030: e01b e960 07a6 162b 73e7 3f9c f173 8224  ...`...+s.?..s.$
00000040: 211e c175 ca2f d7bf 0066 fc79 43cf 9591  !..u./...f.yC...
00000050: db8b bef4 f9f6 c7d0 3d                   ........=
```

It feels you have some other question here. If you're trying to reverse engineer this, that's off topic for StackOverflow, but if you're trying to decode it as you asked, any Base64 decoder will do that. There's no cryptography in your question, but if this is encrypted, and you wish to decrypt it, you will need to find out the data format, the encryption algorithm, and the encryption parameters (including the key). With those, we can help you implement a decryptor. There is no particular way to guess those things. You look them up from whatever generated the data. If you don't have the generator, then that's reverse engineering and there is no simple answer to that question.